# Mysql Left Join return 2 rows except 1

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, for example:

table A have data:

```
id | name
-----------
1  | nik
```

table B have fields:

```
id | id_a ( relation 1 to many to table A ) | name
---------------------------
3  | 1 | mark
4  | 1 | den
```

When i try to make sql request to each table i got only one line

```
# SQL from table A
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE A.id=1

# result is one line - 1  | nik
```

SQL from table B

```
SELECT min(B.id) FROM B WHERE B.id_a = 1

# also return 1 line - 3  | 1 | mark
```

But when i try to execute sql-request with LEFT JOIN i got 2 lines

```
SELECT count(*) FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = ( SELECT min(B.id) FROM B WHERE B.id_a = A.id )
WHERE A.id=1

#will return - 2
```

I am confusing and can`t understand how it possible and how mysql works as this case.

Comment: Try `SELECT count(*) FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON B.id_a = A.id WHERE A.id=1`

Comment: SELECT min(B.id) FROM B WHERE B.id_a = A.id throws an error because A is not invoked.

Comment: Keep in mind that . The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match.. The error is in ( SELECT min(B.id) FROM B WHERE B.id_a = A.id ) . I guess

Comment: @Roy ,
> Try SELECT count(*) FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON B.id_a = A.id WHERE A.i
-  ofc returned 2 lines.

Comment: @P.Salmon,
> Updated text.

Comment: I seem to get `1` as result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43c94f/4/0

Comment: @TiiJ7 You right. In my source i have inner aliases like this
```
SELECT count(*) FROM A
LEFT JOIN B bb ON bb.id = ( SELECT min(bb.id) FROM B WHERE bb.id_a = A.id )
WHERE A.id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys.

Solution is  use table aliases.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = ( SELECT min(b1.id) FROM B as b1 WHERE b1.id_a = A.id )
WHERE A.id=1
```

In subquery add table alias `B as b1` and all works fine